# Regex starts with ends with

Tags: regex

I can't figure out how to write a regex expression that finds a specific string that starts with, for example,  `https://` and ends with `.m3u8`

I managed to write a regex expression that highlights the specific part of the  string that contains the `.m3u8` tag

```
^(.*?(\m3u8\b)[^$]*)$
```

But I need to write an expression that highlights the whole string.

[image]

Added example  text as well

INPUT

```
poster":"https://test/four/v1/video-file1/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/10/22/11/102211-480p.mp4/thumb-33000.jpg","content":{"mp4":[],"dash":"https://test/four/v1/video-file1/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/10/22/11/102211-,480,p.mp4.urlset/manifest.mpd","hls":"https://test/four/v1/video-file1/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/10/22/11/102211-,480,p.mp4.urlset/master.m3u8"},"about":"false","key":"4eeeb77181526bedc1025586d43a70fa","btn-play-pause":"true","btn-stop":"true","btn-fullscreen":"true","btn-prev-next":"false","btn-share":"true","btn-vk-share":"true","btn-twitter-share":"true","btn-facebook-share":"true","btn-google-share":"true","btn-linkedin-share":"true","quality":"true","volume":"true","timer":"true","timeline":"true","iframe-version":"true","max-hls-buffer-size":"10","time-from-cookie":"true","set-prerolls":["https://test/j/v.php?id=645"],"max-prerolls-impressions":1});
```

OUTPUT:

```
https://test/four/v1/video- 
file1/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/10/22/11/102211-,480,p.mp4.urlset/master.m3u8
```

CAUTION: There are two other  HTTP links as well

```
https://test/four/v1/video- 
file1/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/10/22/11/102211-,480,p.mp4.urlset/manifest.mpd
```

And,

```
https://test/four/v1/video-file1/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/10/22/11/102211-480p.mp4/thumb-33000.jpg
```

They must not be highlighted by regex because they start with http but they don't end with .m3u8

Comment: you mean [`https:\/\/(.*)\.m3u8$`](https://regex101.com/r/BRhGi4/1)

Comment: not quite. I have added a couple of examples for reference if you can please verify thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
https:\/\/[^"]+?\.m3u8
```

[As shown here](https://regex101.com/r/7ur7zH/3)

## Explanation -

Since your desired string won't contain double quotes `"`,

`[^"]+?` is a non-greedy (lazy) regex which matches one-or-more characters between `https://` and `.m3u8` which are not `"`

And do note how I've used `?` after `[^"]+` so that it doesn't match any other links too.

Also, `\.` matches a full-stop, while just `.` would have matched **any** character.

Comment: @dmxyler If you feel that an answer has helped you, please consider marking it as helpful, for future references :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
https:\/\/.*\.m3u8
```

It looks for:

1. an exact match of https://
2. followed by .* which means, "any characters will match..."
3. followed by the exact match for .m3u8

This should highlight the complete string.

Comment: It works but if there are multiple http links that i don't need (they don't end with .m3u8) your code finds the first one and the string that ends with .m3u. I need to find a string that ends with .m3u and then check if that string starts with http if so highlight it. 

I added a picture for reference as well please check if you can

Comment: please send simple text with two examples, it will be easier to solve this way.

Comment: Edited with 3 examples. Please verify if you can thank you